# Attempted operating is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, outlook, list-view-threshold

I am trying to access a SharePoint library via Outlook. To do this, I went to the document library, clicked on Library Tools > Library > Connect to outlook.

In outlook I get the error:

> Can error occurred ....... The server returned the following error messages: Attempted operating is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.

I have already increased the threshold to 8000. This however is not the best solution. I am wondering if there is another way around this, since all I want to do is read the data from outlook.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try after disabling the threshold for that library using following code,

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://abc
$web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $True
$list = $web.Lists["ListName"]
$list.EnableThrottling = $False
$list.Update()
$web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $False
$list.EnableThrottling
$web.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```